# IF statement contains SELECT statment

Tags: oracle, plsql

When running this:

```
    create or replace FUNCTION GET_FUNCTION(STATUS_ID IN VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS STATUS_NAME VARCHAR2(255);
    BEGIN 
    IF NVL(STATUS_ID) THEN
          STATUS_NAME:='';
    ELSIF  STATUS_ID LIKE '0' THEN
          STATUS_NAME:='UNASSIGNED'
    ELSE
          SELECT TABLE_A.NAME INTO STATUS_NAME FROM TABLE_A where
    TABLE_A.ID=STATUS_ID;
    END IF;

    RETURN(STATUS_NAME);
    end;
```

I get the following error:

```
Error(9,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ELSE" when expecting one of the following:     
* & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset 
The symbol ";" was substituted for "ELSE" to continue.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You can use `CASEWHEN` for this.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `STATUS_ID LIKE '0'` makes no sense. It's the same as `STATUS_ID = '0'`

Comment: I am new to sql please tell me how can do with case when

Comment: Is it too difficult to search "oracle sql case when" on Google?

Comment: Close the statement "ELSIF  STATUS_ID LIKE '0' THEN
          STATUS_NAME:='UNASSIGNED'" with a ; (semicolon).

And do not use the "select into" statement, unless you know for more than 100% , that the result of the query is just 1 row. If not that you will get an Oracle error: too_many_rows;

Comment: As @wieseman pointed out, your current error is that you don't have ; (semicolon) after the assignment to `STATUS_NAME` in the `ELSIF`, right before `ELSE`. Once you fix that, you will get another syntax error message, about `NVL()`; that function requires two arguments and you only gave it one. Perhaps you meant `IF STATUS_ID IS NULL`? And, `STATUS_ID LIKE '0'` is the same as `STATUS_ID = '0'` (but less efficient). What is the function supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_FUNCTION(STATUS_ID IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS STATUS_NAME VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN 
IF NVL(STATUS_ID) THEN
      STATUS_NAME := '';
ELSIF STATUS_ID = '0' THEN
      STATUS_NAME := 'UNASSIGNED';
ELSE
      SELECT TABLE_A.NAME INTO STATUS_NAME 
      FROM TABLE_A 
      WHERE TABLE_A.ID = STATUS_ID;
END IF;

RETURN STATUS_NAME;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add semicolon after each statement to execute (line 8 in your code - I've added a comment):

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_FUNCTION(STATUS_ID IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS STATUS_NAME VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN 
IF NVL(STATUS_ID) THEN
      STATUS_NAME:='';
ELSIF  STATUS_ID LIKE '0' THEN
      STATUS_NAME:='UNASSIGNED'; /* HERE HAS TO BE A SEMICOLON TOO */
ELSE
      SELECT TABLE_A.NAME INTO STATUS_NAME FROM TABLE_A where
TABLE_A.ID=STATUS_ID;
END IF;

RETURN(STATUS_NAME);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is one is a little bit beter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_FUNCTION(STATUS_ID IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS 
  cursor c_tab (B_STATUS_ID IN TABLE_A.ID%TYPE)
  is
  SELECT TABLE_A.NAME 
  FROM TABLE_A 
  WHERE TABLE_A.ID = B_STATUS_ID;

  STATUS_NAME VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN 
IF NVL(STATUS_ID, -1) = -1 THEN
-- IF STATUS_ID IS NULL THEN  ==> This one is also possible!
      STATUS_NAME := '';
ELSIF STATUS_ID = '0' THEN
      STATUS_NAME := 'UNASSIGNED';
ELSE
      OPEN C_TAB (STATUS_ID);
      FETCH C_TAB INTO STATUS_NAME;
      CLOSE C_TAB;
END IF;

RETURN STATUS_NAME;
END;
```